# Compare old and new values python

Tags: python, compare, store

When I am comparing two urls through `if else` i am getting always else (Prints `test2`), doesnt matter if two values are same. Why? Code is:

```
def derpypost():
    threading.Timer(10.0, derpypost).start()
    print(Fore.CYAN + Style.BRIGHT + "Прошло " + times +
          " минут, начинаю постить картинку в " + vk_group_name)
    print("   Получаю URL картинки")
    real_dp_tags = dp_tags.replace("'", "").replace("'", '')
    for image in Search().query(real_dp_tags).limit(1):
        url = image.image
        source = image.url
        post_tags = image.tags
        sourceurl = image.source_url
    old_url = open('compare.txt', 'r')
    print(old_url.read())
    olded_url = old_url.read()

    if olded_url == url:
        print("test")
    else:
        print('test2')
    old_url.close()
    with open('compare.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(url)
        print('WRITTEN!' + url)
        f.close()
derpypost()
```

In `compare.txt` is - https://example.com/
In url variable - https://example.com

Comment: save the url into an file, read the file back in, compare?

Comment: Also good idea @PatrickArtner. But it will not overload cpu that much?

Comment: @PatrickArtner I did read and write value through file. When i am doing `if` and `else` al always go to esle even that urls are same. P.S code updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

> ```
> old_url = open('compare.txt', 'r')  # stream at pos 0
> print(old_url.read())               # stream at end of file
> olded_url = old_url.read()          # nothing to put into variable
> ```

will not work. Files are stream based, as soon as you consume them once the stream is at the end of the file.

Use

```
def writeFile(urlToWrite):
    fn = 'compare.txt'
    with open(fn, 'w') as createFile:
        createFile.write(urlToWrite)
        print("Wrote: " + urlToWrite)  # if you want it to see on console.

def readFile():
    fn = 'compare.txt'
    old_url = ""
    try:
        with open(fn, 'r') as rf:
            old_url = rf.read()
            print("Read: " + old_url)  # if you want it to see on console.
    except FileNotFoundError: # create file if not exists
        writeFile("")
    return old_url

curr_url = "tata"
old = readFile()
if old != curr_url:
    writeFile(curr_url)
```

Output (after 1st using tata, then tattoo for `curr_url`):

```
Read: tata
Wrote: tattoo
```